# Conditional Formatting - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I hope you guys can help me - I have been scratching my head at this for the last day.

I have a range C5:F which containers both numbers and text (its a reference number that looks similar to MAE017245).  I would like to look up this range and if it matches the same text and numbers found in column S5:S, it must highlight that reference number in column S5:S to show that it is found in range C5:F.

Hope this is a quick one for you guys.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `MATCH()` function? Share a sample workbook.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

**Use this formula** in conditional formatting.

```
=IFNA(MATCH(L5,FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN($C$5:$C,$D$5:$D,$E$5:$E,$F$5:$F)), UNIQUE(FLATTEN($C$5:$C,$D$5:$D,$E$5:$E,$F$5:$F))<>""), 0),0)>1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, yes, I can do this already, but the thing is that it needs to check C:C, D:D, E:E, and F:F to see if it matches S5:S.  I have created a test sheet which you can use to see what I mean...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aVDBSfksgvppy50kPe_UvFncfaUzgTVIK4K8nUA04A0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Access denied [You can't access](https://i.imgur.com/IYhjpfd.png), Please [share everyone](https://i.imgur.com/Oh4SUnW.gifv), Note that your email addess is visible to anyone who accessed the sheet.

Comment: Done - apologies

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(H5, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $C$5:$F)))
```

[image]